# I am trying to get driver related to vehicle using vue js

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-api

I have shown vechicle data just I want to get driver data related to vehicle but unfortuntly i am getting error undefined please help me how can i show into draggablelist thank u ?

**Controller**

```
public function index(){

  return $vehicles = Vehicle::with('driver')->get();
   
  
}
```

**template view**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <q-card-section>
                    <div class="tw-grid">
                        <div class="tw-col-span-6">
                            <DraggableList
                                v-model="api.drivers"
                                label-key="username"
                                :colors="colors"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </q-card-section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**vue js**

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {

            api: {
                vehicles: [],
                drivers: []
            }
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.fetchVehiclesDriver()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchVehiclesDriver () {
            this.$api.get(this.apiRoute('client.vector.driver', {
            }))
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    this.api.vehicles = data.vehicles
                    this.api.drivers  = data.vehicles.driver

                    console.log(data.vehicles.driver) // undefined
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the API doesn't send back `data.vehicles.driver` then no frontend code will help you fix that. Check that your backend is querying and returning the correct data.

Comment: Yoduh I am getting json data from back end just I need to get driver related to vehicles

Comment: do you know for sure that the data you return from the backend, `$vehicles` also contains the driver data?  if so, you can always check the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see the entire response.  if the driver data exists, it'll be there.  if you need help figuring out how to extract the data from that JSON, paste the JSON in your question and I can help figure out the correct JS to get to it.